# Code Formatting in String - can I make text bold?

Tags: vb.net, vbscript

I am working in Windows Workflow and want to use a string expression in vb. I'm wondering, is there a way I can format the text? Like, if I want it bold or something?

Here is the code:

```
String.Format("I'm the important message! Read me first.".ToString())
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. I know very, very little about vb code and this is just something I'm seeing if it can be done to help someone with a message :)

Comment: A string is data, data doesnt have bold or italic etc.  Those would be elements of the UI

Comment: Drat. Is there another way to generate a message in vb that would allow text formatting?

Comment: *A string is data, data doesnt have bold or italic etc.*  **HOW** you display it may allow bold...if it is for a MessageBox, that is what the icons are for

Comment: Winforms?  asp.net?  This answer will probably differ depending on what you're using to display it on.

Comment: Asp.net... Ok, I'll poke around a bit in the message editor and see if there are any formatting options in there. It didn't look like it since it's not a WYSIWYG type of editor. But maybe there are some commands that can be used. I appreciate you guys offering your input.

Comment: if it's asp.net then you can likely inline some style and bold it either with the depricated`<b>` tag or more ideally add some inline css style to it (font-weight:bold).

Answer (score 1):

You can use a textbox to make it bold

```
Text_string.FontBold = True
```

As others have already mentioned, string is a data and cannot be bolded.

Answer (score -3):

Use string format function to make string bold

`Comment = String.Format("<strong> Warning : </strong>")`

Comment: This is not the goal of string.format. String.format is intended for formatting variables within a string. This will just return exactlty what is in the String.Format() since there are are no additional parameters used